# Iphone SDK - tap to undo a zoom inside of a scroll view

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I was just wondering how I can get a single tap to undo the zoom inside of a scroll view? I cant seem to figure it out.

I was also wondering how do you know what size to set your scroll view contentSize, as I find this issue a little confusing at the moment I have it set at 460x320.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to subclass UIScrollView and intercept the tap, then just set the `zoomScale` property to 1.0. You can also intercept the tap from a containing view. Hard to tell which is simpler, depends on your needs and view hierarchy. In general, I find it a bit hard to work with scroll views. Takes some experimentation to get things working the way you want to sometimes. Check out Apple's [ScrollView suite example code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/index.html). It does pretty much exactly what you are asking for.